# AvalonDock 2.0 LayoutDocumentPaneGroup Scrollbar Visibility

Tags: avalondock

Does anyone know if there a scrollbar for the AvalonDock.LayoutDocumentPaneGroup ? It displays  only as many tabs as will fit the width. Is there a scrollbar capability (as in Visual Studio IDE) that will allow you to horizontally scroll through the tabs? If so, can you please explain what property needs to be set?